# Can we omit "as" with verbs like "to classify"

Tags: conjunctions

For example, can we say "It has been classified a threat" in colloquial English, or do we have to use 'as'?

Second question: Is the question title correct? I'm not sure if that "with" is correct.

Comment: There are only 6 written instances of [*were classified illegal*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22were+classified+illegal%22), compared to over 900 of [*were classified **as** illegal*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22were+classified+as+illegal%22). But I wouldn't say discarding ***as*** is "ungrammatical" - more a matter of established idiomatic preference and stylistic choice.

Comment: Yes, the question is correct. See: http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/classify       for examples of different prepositions that can follow *classify*, depending on the context.

Comment: There are very few relevant hits that seem to turn up in a Google search for "classified them a". 'Can we say ...' questions are usually answerable by 'You just did.' But essentially, usage drives acceptability (even, eventually, grammaticality) and I'd avoid using dubious constructions. // 'It has been called / labelled / considered / deemed / designated a threat' seem to be used far more commonly, but what on earth do you mean by 'verbs like ... _classify_'? _Regard_? Verb behaviour is notoriously idiosyncratic.

Comment: *A threat* is a noun objective complement when *as* is omitted. This omission does not make the sentence wrong.

Comment: They're both correct, just slightly different nuances.  "It has been classified a threat" uses "threat" as a classification label.  "It has been classified as a threat" uses "threat" as a descriptive term for the nature of "it".

Comment: The context matters hugely. Please consider *Yo, Flunky; classify these verbs* as compared to *… classify these verbs as transitive or intransitive…*

How could either be considered *wrong*, please?